# How to better structure this context and show for each selected ticket type the custom fields associated with that ticket type?

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to develop a context like it is in the image.

[image]

So for the "screen 1" of the image I have a "single.blade.php" file associated with this route:

```
// Route for congress details page:
Route::get('/congress/{id}/{slug?}', [
    'uses' => 'FrontController@show',
    'as'   =>'congresses.show'
]);
```

So when user acesses "http://project.test/congress/1/congress-title-test/" he acesses the congress details page. In this page besides the congress details there is a form for the user select the quantities that he want for each ticket type.

This form has this select menu with this name:

```
 <select name="types[{{ $type->name }}]">
```

An has this action and route:

// form action

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('congresses.storeQuantities', ['id' => $congress->id, 'slug' => $congress->slug])}}">
```

// Form route:

```
Route::post('/congress/{id}/{slug?}/registration', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@storeQuantity',
    'as'   =>'congresses.storeQuantities'
]);
```

When user clicks "Next" the form is submited and its necessary to store the selected quantities for each ticket type by the user. And is also necessary to get some information from DB and then redirect to the registration.blade.php page. I created a RegistrationController for handle this.

Then, in the screen 2 of the image is necessary to show in the first step a summary of the selected quantties by the user and is also necessary to show the registration form.

The registration form:

- has always a section "Buyer information" for the user that is doing the registration introduce his name, surname and email.
- If the congress has paid ticket types there is also the "Billing information" section".
- If the congress table has the column "collect_info_from_all_participants" with value "1" it should appear for each ticket type selected by the user a section to collect the name and surname of the participant for each selected ticket. But then, each ticket type can have custom questions associated. For example as it is in the image the ticket type "full access" has the custom questions "Phone" and the ticket type "Basic" dont have any custom question. So, its necessary to show the custom questions associated with each ticket type.

To develop this context when the user click in "Next" in the first screen of the image, in the congres details page,  the RegistrationController has the `storeQuantity()` method that:

- stores the selected quantities
- check if the congress has the column "collect_info_from_all_participants" with value "1"
- for each selected ticket type get the custom questions associated with that ticket type
- return all of this things to the registration.blade.php view.

So I have in the RegistrationController the storeQuantity method:

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller

 public function storeQuantity(Request $request, $id, $slug=null){
        $typeQuantities = $request->get('types');

        $allParticipants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;

        $total = 0;
        foreach($typeQuantities as $typeName => $quantity){

            $type = TicketType::where('name', $typeName)->firstOrFail();
            $price = $type->price;

            $customQuestionsOfTicketType = $type->questions;

            $selectedTypes[$type->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
            $selectedTypes[$type->name]['price'] = $price;
            $selectedTypes[$type->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
            $total+=  $selectedTypes[$type->name]['subtotal'];
            $selectedTypes[$type->name]['total'] = $total;
        }

        Session::put('selectedTypes', $selectedTypes);
        Session::put('allParticipants' , $allParticipants);
        Session::put('customQuestionsOfTicketType' , $customQuestionsOfTicketType);
        return redirect(route('congresses.registration',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
    }

    public function displayRegistrationPage(Request $request, $id, $slug=null){
         $selectedTypes = Session::get('selectedTypes');
         $allParticipants = Session::get('allParticipants');
        return view('congresses.registration', ['selectedTypes' => $selectedTypes, 'allParticipants' => $allParticipants]);
}

}
```

// route for displayRegistrationPage

```
Route::get('/congress/{id}/{slug?}/registration', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@displayRegistrationPage',
    'as'   =>'congresses.registration'
]);
```

In the registration.blade.php (screen 2 of the image) first I have the summary that shows the selected ticket types, subtotal, total:

```
@foreach($selectedTypes as $k=>$selectedType)
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <span>{{$k}}</span>
        <span>{{$selectedType['quantity']}}</span>
        <span>{{ number_format($selectedType['price'], 2)}}€</span>
        <span>{{ number_format($selectedType['subtotal'], 2)}}€</span>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Then I have a multi step registration form. The first step is the registration form. The step 2 is for the user select the payment type. The step 3 is for the user to introduce the payment data. To navigate between the forms I have some jquery but should not be relevant for the question.

My doubts are mainly about the first step.

**Registration.blade.php multi step form:**

```
    <div class="registration_form">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
            <li class="">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Step 1 - Registration Information</a>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"> Step 2 - Payment Methods</a>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"> Step 3 - Payment</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <form method="post">
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="step1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                    <h6>Buyer Information</h6>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="surname" value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->surname : old('surname')}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emai" id="email" value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}">
                    </div>

                    <!-- If the congress has paid ticket types  -->
                    @if( array_sum(array_column($selectedTypes, 'price')) > 0 )
                        <h6>Billing Information</h6>
                        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                            <label for="inputName">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                            <label for="inputName">Country</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
                        </div>
                        <!-- ... -->
                    @endif

                    <!-- If its necessary to collect data from all participants  -->
                    @if (!empty($allParticipants))
                        @if($allParticipants == 1)
                            @foreach($selectedTypes as $k=>$selectedType)
                                <h6>Participant - 1 - {{$k}}</h6>
                                <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                                    <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="surname" value="">
                                </div>

                                <!-- If the ticket type has custom questions show the questions and if the are required add the required property  -->
                                @if (!empty($customQuestions))
                                    @if(count($customQuestions) > 0)
                                        @foreach($customQuestions as $customQuestion)
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="test">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="" value="">
                                            </div>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    @endif

                    <button type="button" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="btn btn-primary next-step">
                       GO to Step 2
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="step2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                    <form method="post">
                        <h6>Select the payment method</h6>
                        <!-- radio buttons fields -->
                        <button type="button" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="btn btn-primary next-step"> Go to step 3 </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="step3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
                   <form method="post">
                        <h6>Payment</h6>
                        <!-- payment fields -->
                        <button type="button" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="btn btn-primary next-step"> Confirm </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Doubts and issues:**

- With this code the custom questions that exist for a congress are appearing for all ticket types. But the custom questions should only appear for the ticket types that are associated with that custom questions;
- With this code Im passing many arrays to the view but this dont seems very correct, do you know how to have only one array with all necessary data ready?
- Also the code flow dont seems very correct with the storeQuantity method of the RegistrationController doing everything. Do you know if there is a better flow for develop this context? Since this is a mutli step form maybe there is a better way to organize the context.
- Also I have about if is necessary to have a form in each step or just a global form. The first step is to collect the information about the user that is doing the registration and other participants. The second step is to select the payment type. The third step is to introduce the payment data and pay. But if the user selected a payment metohd that is not immediate, in the third step instead of user introduce the payment data, its presented to the user some codes generated so the user can do the payment. And Im with doubt about how to organize this in terms of necessary forms and  necessary routes.

**Table relationships relevant for this question context:**

```
1 to many between congress and registration (a congress can have many registrations)
1 to many between registration and participants (a registration can have man participants)
1 to many between congress and ticket types (a congress can have many ticket types)
1 to many between ticket types and ticket_type_questions (a ticket type can have many custom questions)
1 to many between questions and ticket_type_questions (a question can be associated with many ticket types)


// TicketType Model
class TicketType extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', '...', 'congress_id'
    ];

    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }

    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'ticket_type_questions');
    }
}

// Question Model
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'question', 'congress_id',
    ];

    public function ticket_types(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\TicketType', 'ticket_type_questions');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Q: **With this code the custom questions that exist for a congress are appearing for all ticket types. But the custom questions should only appear for the ticket types that are associated with that custom questions;**

Given

```
public function storeQuantity(Request $request, $id){
    ...
    $customQuestionsOfTicketType = $type->questions;
    ...
}
```

you overwrite the value of `customQuestionsOfTicketType` at every cycle. Instead that could be an attribute of the `$selectedTpyes[$type->name]`, like:

```
$selectedTpyes[$type->name]['questions'] = $type->questions;
```

Then in the view you'll cycle `$selectedTpyes[$type->name]` instead of `$customQuestions`.

---

- Q: **With this code Im passing many arrays to the view but this dont seems very correct, do you know how to have only one array with all necessary data ready?**

You're passing to the view a list of participants (`allParticipants`) and a list of types (`selectedTypes`) which are two separate entities, which is fine in my opinion. With my solution above you'd get rid of `$customQuestionsOfTicketType`.

---

- Q: **Also the code flow dont seems very correct with the storeQuantity method of the RegistrationController doing everything and also returning a view for a POST request. Do you know if there is a better flow for develop this context? Since this is a mutli step form maybe there is a better way to organize the context.**

I don't see big issues here, except I'd separate the information retrieval from the Controller, moving it to a separate class which would be a dependency of the controller.

You could inject this new class through [dependency injection](http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html).

You could use the Repository pattern in order to access the database resources. If you're not comfortable with it, here a couple of lectures:

- http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/More/Repository/README.html
- http://shawnmc.cool/the-repository-pattern

and a Laravel package which could help you:

- https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository

---

- Q: **Also I have about if is necessary to have a form in each step or just a global form. The first step is to collect the information about the user that is doing the registration and other participants. The second step is to select the payment type. The third step is to introduce the payment data and pay. But if the user selected a payment metohd that is not immediate, in the third step instead of user introduce the payment data, its presented to the user some codes generated so the user can do the payment. And Im with doubt about how to organize this in terms of necessary forms and necessary routes.**

This is an application design problem, this is up to you basically. Given the context I'd separate the steps where the `/step1` shows some form fields, `/step2` elaborates the step 1 data and return further fields, and so on ...

Comment: Thanks relative to question 1, changing in the controller to "$selectedTpyes[$type->name]['questions'] = $type->questions;" and in the registration.blade.php with this code its not showing the question:

Comment: "@if (!empty($allParticipants))@if($allParticipants == 1) @foreach($selectedTypes as $k=>$selecteTtype)<h6>Participant - 1 - {{$k}}</h6><div> <label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" class="" id="name" value=""></div> <div class="form-group"><label for="surname">Surname</label><input type="text"name="surname" id="surname" value=""></div>@foreach($selectedType['questions'] as $k => $customQuestion)
<div><label for="teste">{{$customQuestion}}</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="" value=""></div>@endforeach@endforeach@endif
@endif"

Comment: Relative to the third question I forget to add a doubt, I updated the question with that. The doubt is if is necessary to have a form in each step or just a global form. The first step is to collect the information about the user that is doing the registration and of other participants. The second step is to select the payment type. The third step is to introduce the payment data.

Comment: But there is a payment method that the payment is not immediate, so if the user selects this payment method in the third step instead of user introduce the payment data, its presented to the user some codes generated so the user can do the payment. And Im with doubt about how to organize this in terms of forms that are necessary and routes.

Comment: About the questions not showing, you need to debug, but since the questions are related to a type, this should be the right approach. Just `dd($selectedTypes)` before returning the view. I'll update the answer with your doubt.

Comment: With that it appears that the ticket type full access have two questions associated: array:1 [▼  "full access" => array:1 [▼ "questions" => Collection {#261 ▼ #items: array:2 [▶]} ]]. But in the registration.blade.php it appears "Undefined index: full acccess".

Comment: Maybe this is because questions is a collection. Use it as an array: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-toarray

Comment: Thanks, but the custom questions dont appear. In the controller "            $selectedTypes[$type->name]['questions'] = $type->questions->toArray();" And in the registration.blade.php:
"

Comment: "@if (!empty($allParticipants)) @if($allParticipants == 1)  @foreach($selectedRtypes as $k=>$selectedRtype)  <h6>Participant - 1 - {{$k}}</h6> <div class="form-group font-size-sm"> <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" value=""></div> <div class="form-group font-size-sm"> <label for="surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="surname" value=""></div>

Comment: @foreach($customQuestions as $customQuestion) <div class="form-group"> <label for="">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="" value=""> </div>@endforeach  @endforeach@endif@endif"

Comment: And the step1, step2, and step3 are in the same page. Is a form with 3 steps. So there isnt a specific page for each step.

Comment: This "            $selectedTypes[$type->name]['questions'] = $type->questions;
" seems that dont returns nothing, that is empty. It shows "Collection {#254 ▼
  #items: []
}".

Comment: Look at the last part of the answer, I added the missing part. 
I can't tell you exactly from here what's the issue in your code. 
You should split the form in three steps, with three diffrent methods in your controller respectively. Then you need to debug, step by step, checking the data at each step of the process.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue, the question is not appearing for each ticket type is not working and is just about the step 1. The question dont appears with "$selectedTpyes[$type->name]['questions'] = $type->questions;". This is empty, it shows "Collection {#254 ▼ #items: [] }".

Comment: As I said, you need to debug it. The code as I see it here, looks good to me. You should check the value of `$type->questions` at every cycle dumping the data before rendering the view.